# Impala ODBC/JDBC bad performance - rows fetch is very slow from a remote server compared with NN

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, odbc, impala, unixodbc

In the NameNode of CDH, when I run the query via odbc script (php/perl or python), I can fetchAll results (**9.2M**) in a variable in about **30 seconds**, but when I tried with the same script/query on another remote 2 servers, the execution time was in first server **28 min** and in second **17 min**.

To exclude the assuming that it's a network speed issue, I fetch the result on a file and then I copied it with scp command to the first remote server, and it finished in ~**40 seconds**.

What I observe in Query info in CM that there is a big different between the *Threads: Network Send Wait Time* values in the 3 queries :
in NN query: **9.40s**
in 1st remote server: **16.7m**
in 2nd remote server: **26.8m**

And also I try an java script with Impala JDBC, but the results in NN are already not stimulate to continue.

But so far I cann't find where is the problem and how can I resolve it.
*NB*: I'm working on CDH 5.12.0/Impala 2.9.0, I installed Impala ODBC 2.5.37.1014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly and after almost 6 months I have found the solution!

It was always about my 1024 limitition remark, the row batch limitation was from BATCH_SIZE max value (1024), in the last versions (CDH 5.14/Impala 2.11) we have a new effective range is 1-65536.

1-1024: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/impala_batch_size.html
1-65536: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/impala_batch_size.html

So when I increase it throgh a odbc.ini with SSP_BATCH_SIZE I can benifit from increasing the other odbc parameters (RowsFetchedPerBlock / TSaslTransportBufSize) and the rows can be fetched in a seconds (~45 secs) instead of tens of minutes.

Link: http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Impala-ODBC-JDBC-bad-performance-rows-fetch-is-very-slow-from-a/m-p/61152

Thanks all for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mention of the JDBC connector version used.

There might be more than one server in your cluster where Impala daemons are run, please make the respective changes
in your JDBC connection URL and verify the performance on those servers too.

Just in case you missed to refer the documentation (https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/impala_jdbc.html) , pay attention to this extract:

> The latest JDBC driver, corresponding to Hive 0.13, provides
>   substantial performance improvements for Impala queries that return
>   large result sets. Impala 2.0 and later are compatible with the Hive
>   0.13 driver. If you already have an older JDBC driver installed, and are running Impala 2.0 or higher, consider upgrading to the latest
>   Hive JDBC driver for best performance with JDBC applications.

Since you are using a remote machine to access Impala, refer to this information also:

> If you are using JDBC-enabled applications on hosts outside the CDH
>   cluster, you cannot use the CDH install procedure on the non-CDH
>   hosts. Install the JDBC driver on at least one CDH host .... Then
>   download the JAR files to each client machine that will use JDBC with
>   Impala...

If not done earlier, update the JDBC connector, and make sure that all the impalad instances are running.
Then compare the performance results of ODBC and JDBC.

This link also is worth refering:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/impala_troubleshooting.html

**Update 1:**

Reference#1: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Impala-JDBC-10x-Slower-Vs-Shell/m-p/51779

As recommended in the reference, try adding the below parameters to the JDBC connection string and check the log:

> ;LogLevel=6;LogPath=/path/to/directory

Reference#2: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-2651 you might consider the below setting:

> SET disable_codegen=true;

**Update 2:** I guess you already have these below mentioned jars in at least one Impala server, in your cluster.

```
commons-logging-X.X.X.jar
hadoop-common.jar
hive-common-X.XX.X-cdhX.X.X.jar
hive-jdbc-X.XX.X-cdhX.X.X.jar
hive-metastore-X.XX.X-cdhX.X.X.jar
hive-service-X.XX.X-cdhX.X.X.jar
httpclient-X.X.X.jar
httpcore-X.X.X.jar
libfb303-X.X.X.jar
libthrift-X.X.X.jar
log4j-X.X.XX.jar
slf4j-api-X.X.X.jar
slf4j-logXjXX-X.X.X.jar
```

Please copy these jars to the machine from where you try to access Impala through JDBC code.  Make sure that these jars are in your *classpath* and execute the JDBC code.

Comment: I will test this.

Comment: I can't install hive-jdbc in my centos 6.9.
It's give : No package hive-jdbc available.
Rmq: I don't think I'm concerned by the Reference #1 & #2, because my queries are excuted without errors. The problem is in fetchAll rows that is veeeeery slow on a outside cluster servers.

Comment: Updated the answer.  The investigation is about the delay, and the logs might show what is taking time.

Comment: I'll test *Update2*

Comment: I tested the JDBC with hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.12.0.jar, it's works now but unfortunately always the same problem, in namenode it's took about 50 secs but in outside cluster server the fetch is very slow (took ~20min).

Comment: unfortunately not yet!

Comment: As the problem still remains open, generate the log once and see. You might find something interesting.

Comment: What I observe in ClouderaODBCDriverforImpala_connection_0.log file, that the PrepareTResultForDataRetrieval in the 2 cases repeats ~150 times, even if the RowsFetchedPerBlock is 10000 !!!

Comment: it look like RowsFetchedPerBlock is fixed on 1024

Comment: Before you tweak the driver configuration, can you run the Java/JDBC code in the NN with the same JDBC configuration (without changing any connection parameter) and share the results? What do you mean by "And also I try an java script with Impala JDBC, but the results in NN are already not stimulate to continue." in your question?

Comment: In effect, I already test a Java/JDBC code in the NN, and the results is good (9.2M in about 60secs), but in the outside servers the fetch always is slow.

Comment: Strange. Please try with latest Impala JDBC driver https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors/impala-jdbc/latest.html